# What versions of Chrome supports HKCU Native Messaging Host

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I am developing a Chrome Extension that interacts with a Native Messaging Application for Windows. The current documentation states the the Native Messaging Host can be registered in both HKLM and HKCU. The question is what versions of the Chrome Browser support registration of the Native Messaging Host in HKCU?

Of note: I saw that support for HKCU was addressed in issue #321480 (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321480), and I also saw the code in trunk. What I can't figure out is which versions of Chrome include this new code.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should update your chrome to the newest version(above 34+)
2. You can register to HKCU and It will work